# Collision of 8 Digit, Base-36 Numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have an algorithm that generates a random 8 digit, base 36 number with uniform distribution.  Thus, this algorithm can generate $36^8$ unique numbers.

I run my algorithm 10,000 times, and write down the result on a large piece of paper.  At the end of doing this, what is the probability of the same number being written down twice on my piece of paper?

---

This looks to me like an application of the birthday problem.  Therefore, the probability of there *being a collision* on my piece of paper should be:

$$1 - \frac{(36^8)!}{(36^8)^{10000}(36^8-10000)!}$$

However, computing $(36^8)^{10000}$ is computationally difficult.  Is there an alternative way to compute this probability with high accuracy?

Comment: With $n=36^8$, you can rewrite the fraction as
$$\frac{n}{n}\cdot\frac{n-1}{n}\cdots\frac{n-9999}{n}\cdot$$
With this and Maxima, I find that your probability is $$1.77215913956941117517... \cdot 10^{-5}$$

Comment: It can be approximated with a Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jean-Claude Arbaut pointed out in a comment,

$$\frac{n!}{n^{10000}{(n-10000)}!} = \frac{n}{n}\cdot\frac{n-1}{n}\cdots\frac{n-9999}{n}$$

If we make the approximations $n(n-9999) \approx (n-1)(n-9998) \approx \ldots \approx(n-4999.5)^2$, we get

$$\frac{n!}{n^{10000}{(n-10000)}!} \approx \left(1-\frac{4999.5}{n}\right)^{10000} \approx 1 - \frac{49995000}{n}$$

So the probability of a collision is about $\dfrac{49995000}{n} \approx 0.0000177217$. This agrees with Jean-Claude's exact calculation to five significant figures.

Answer (score 1):

If you expand the factorial on the top and then cancel the factorial in the bottom, you have a numerator of $$(36^8)(36^8-1)(36^8-2)\cdots(36^8-9999)$$

As $36^8$ is much larger than $9999$, this numerator is going to be only slightly smaller than $(36^8)^{10000}$. Hence we are subtracting off a number only minimally smaller than $1$. This leaves us with a probability of collision that is extremely tiny.

A Poisson approximation could also be used, but I am not an expert in such.